# VB.NET LINQ Result Set Manipulation

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID / Description / textValue / dateValue / timeValue / Type
1  / FRRSD       / NULL      / 2010-04-16 00:00:00.000 / NULL / classdates
```

Now I've got a LINQ command to pull only the rows where the type is classdates from this table:

```
 Dim dbGetRegisterDates As New dcConfigDataContext
 Dim getDates = (From p In dbGetRegisterDates.webConfigOptions _
                Where p.Type = "classdates" _
                Select p)
```

I now want to display the data in five different labels like so:

`lblClass1.Text = "Your class is from " & getDates.Description("FRRSD").dateValue & "to " & getDates.Description("FRRCD").dateValue`

`lblClass2.Text = "Your class is from " & getDates.Description("SORSD").dateValue & "to " & getDates.Description("SORCD").dateValue`

Basically, I want to pull a row based on the description column value and then return the datevalue column value from that same row.

Comment: You want to display the dateValue where the Description = "FRRCD" . . . 5 times?  repeated?  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: No, I'd have lbl1Class.Text where the Description = FRRSD, lbl2Class.Text where the Description = SORSD, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know VB.NET syntax very well, so I'll write it in C#, but you could create a Dictionary of descriptions to dates.

```
var res = (from p dbGetRegisterDates.webConfigOptions
           where p.Type == "classdates"
           select new 
            {
               p.Description,
               p.dateValue
            }).ToDictionary(x=>x.Description, x=>x.dateValue);
```

then you can do

```
lblClass1.Text = string.Format("Your class is from {0} to {1}", res["FRRSD"], res["FRRCD"])
```

You'll probably want to do some checking that they exist too. Also, if the Description isn't unique in the results, you'll get an exception

Answer (score 1):

This would work for you:

```
lblClass1.Text = From c in getDates Where Description = "FRRCD"
         Select string.Format("Your class is from {0} to {0}", c.dateValue)

lblClass2.Text = From c in getDates Where Description = "SORCD"
         Select string.Format("Your class is from {0} to {0}", c.dateValue)
```

I suspect though that what you really want is to create a note for each record you find.  More like:

```
Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
For each c in getDates
    sb.Append(string.Format("<p><b>{0}</b>:  Your class is from {1} to {1}.</p>" _
        , c.Description, c.dateValue)
Next
classNotes = sb.toString()
```

And then in your page you'd put `<% = classNotes %>`